# Send a .txt or word file from android to laptop over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am able to save my last know location in a word file in internal storage in a text file.Now every time the location is changed I have to transmit it to my laptop to give him the location intelligence.

Please let me know how can I use Bluetooth/WiFi to send data to laptop whenever there is a change in location coordinates? Definitely it needs to be automated.

Comment: Use background service for monitor the location change...

Comment: Ram,please elaborate....

Answer (score 0):

At first you try to send data through Bluetooth from device to your laptop using Inputstream class.After that create one background service in android,implements locationlistener.like

```
    public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener
```

Now include the data sending code in the onLocationChanged method.

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //Sending data from bluetooth. 
 }
```

Background service is always active for watching the location updates.
If you want to send from WIFI,for that you have to go for middleware concept to send and receive gps location content file.